# Displaying specific thumbnail size in single.php

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

Currently I'm building a Wordpress theme and I'm trying to display a specific image size, which is cropped in my `single.php`, and thus on individual post pages and not having any luck.

Here's my `functions.php`:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_image_size('new-thumbnail-size',600,340, true);
```

Here's my `single.php`:

```
<?php if( get_the_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
    <div class = 'postImgCon'>
        <div class="feat-img">
             <?php the_post_thumbnail('new-thumbnail-size'); ?>
        </div>
    </div> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the correct functions to declare support for post thumbnails and add an image size but you need to do so inside the `after_setup_theme` hook.

Inside `functions.php` change:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_image_size('new-thumbnail-size',600,340, true);
```

To:

```
function wpse_setup_theme() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

    add_image_size( 'new-thumbnail-size', 600, 340, true );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse_setup_theme' );
```

Also you're using the wrong function to check if a post has a thumbnail. It should still work but here's the correct approach.

Inside `single.php` change:

```
<?php if( get_the_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
```

To:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
```

Finally you need to be aware that any images you've already uploaded won't have been cropped to 600 x 340 so you won't get the output you're expecting. You need to regenerate your existing images. Take a look at the following plugin for that: https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Comment: Thanks Nathan that seems to have worked, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this
....

```
 <div class="feat-img">
   <?php echo the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, "new-thumbnail-size'); ?>
```

....

Comment: This is incorrect for multiple reasons. `the_post_thumbnail` is used to output the thumbnail and doesn't return a value so echo is redundant. `the_post_thumbnail` doesn't accept a post ID as one of its arguments. You open the thumbnail size string with a double quote and close it with a single quote.